# checking for first key in map with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got the following component in ReactJS

```
var MainMenu = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                    console.log(this.props.groupsData);
                    var categories = this.props.groupsData.objects.map(function(obj){
                        return (<li><a href="#">{obj.display_name}</a></li>);   
                    });
                    return (<div className="MainMenu">
                            <ul className="nav nav-pills">{categories}</ul>

                        </div>);
                }
            });
```

Now, I wish to add `className='active'` to the `<li>` element if its the first in the map. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JS in your expression](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#child-expressions)

```
var MainMenu = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    console.log(this.props.groupsData);
    var categories = this.props.groupsData.objects.map(function(obj, index) {
      // You can have a JavaScript expression in your expression 
      return ( <li className={index == 0 ? 'active' : ''}> <a href="#">{
        obj.display_name
      }</a></li> );
    });
    return ( <div className="MainMenu" >
      <ul className="nav nav-pills" >{
        categories
      }</ul>

   </div> );
  }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, I tried using an expression before, but got a strange error, but this works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Documentation on the .map method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map